# search:field_name parameter combined numeric matching doesn't work

Tags: channel-entries, bug, parameters

I want to use the numeric matching possibility of EE with 2 conditions to only show entries that are in a certain range of values.

I tried these two but none of them works (it just shows nothing) :

```
search:cost=">={embed:the_cost-from}" search:cost="<={embed:the_cost-to}"

search:cost=">={embed:the_cost-from}|<={embed:the_cost-to}"
```

If I ask just for one search:cost numeric matching (`search:cost=">={embed:the_cost-from}"`  or  `search:cost=">={embed:the_cost-to}"`) it displays something but not what I want because I want something from a range.

Is this a EE bug or simply not intended or I just do it wrong?

EE 2.9.2

Answer (score 1):

EE doesn't support that range syntax out of the box. It expects a *single numeric value* after the operator.

You'd need either the Query module or an add-on like [Solspace Super Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search) or [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search), by yours truly. With the latter, you *can* use this syntax:

```
{exp:low_search:results search:cost=">=10|<=20"}
```

Or use the [Ranges filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#ranges), like so:

```
{exp:low_search:results range:cost="10|20"}
```

...or split up into two parameters:

```
{exp:low_search:results range-from:cost="10" range-to:cost="20"}
```

Note that the `{exp:low_search:results}` tag is interchangeable with the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag.

Comment: One clarifying addendum I'd add is that EE only supports multiple `search` parameters on *different fields* - so including `search:cost` twice does not result in two `WHERE` statements in the query - only one will be used.

Comment: Indeed, this is true for *any* parameter. Tags accept only unique parameter names, and uses the last one on the tag if multiple of the same param are given.

Comment: @Derek Hogue Absolutely, that is what I noticed, the second crushes the first one.

Comment: @Low Thanks for your answer. In fact I already use Supersearch for this project so I'm gonna use the `customfield-from` and `customfield-to` but I was thinking about using the simple `{exp:channel:entries}` tags so I could use these parameters : `display_by="week" limit="1"`  because I don't see how to mimic this in `{exp:super_search:results}` to only show results that have been added whithin the last 7 days.